# Number of edges of tensor product and lexicographic product of graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be graphs.

The tensor product (categorical product) $G \times H$ is defined on vertex set $V(G) \times V(H)$ 
with adjacency relationship $((x_1,y_1) \backsim_{G \times H} (x_2,y_2)) \equiv (x_1 \backsim_G x_2 \wedge y_1 \backsim_H y_2)$.

The lexicographic product $G[H]$ is defined on vertex set $V(G) \times V(H)$ 
with adjacency relationship $(x,y) \backsim (x',y') \equiv\begin{cases}
x \not= x' \wedge x \backsim_G x'\\
x = x' \wedge y \backsim_H y'
\end{cases}$.

What are the number of edges $||G \times H||$ and $||G[H]||$? I am happy to prove it myself but I need the **answer** right **now**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $||G \times H|| = 2 \cdot ||G|| \cdot ||H||$ and $||G[H]|| = |G|\cdot ||H|| + |H|^2 \cdot ||G||$